# nslookup script to loop through IP addresses in perl

Tags: perl, nslookup

Stackoverflow community,

I am bran new to PERL scripting and need help [part of this script was from an internet source] to do an nslookup on a list of IP addresses in a file and loop through each one until I get to the end.  If the domain name does not exist then do X, if it does do Y.

information for the below :

```
-existent - is a key word when nslookup aborts
name - is a key word when it works
listofhosts - is my ip address list
```

Thank you any help is greatly appreciated

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!c:\perl64\bin

use strict;
use warnings;

my $noname=-existent;
my $name=name;

open IPADDRESSES,("c:\\perl64\\scripts\\listofhosts.txt") or die("File could not be opened :$!");
my @list=<IPADDRESSES>;
foreach my $list(@list);
my $results=`nslookup $list`;
CHOMP ($list);
if ($noname) {
    print ("no name")}
elsif ($name){
    print ("IP address $list:\n");
    print ("=\n");
    print ("DNS name:$results\n");
}

close (IPADDRESSES);
```

Comment: Your script will have returned errors when you ran it. Have you tried to correct those errors?

Comment: Welcome to SO and Perl.  Your script has two syntax errors.  Bareword 'name' on line 8.  And a for loop without a block on line 12.  Probably should address those in your code first and then edit your question.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Socket's `inet_ntoa(inet_aton($name_or_ip))` will resolve a DNS name. (It will also check your `hosts` file, or whatever other checks your OS normally does).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feedback - I am going to work on correcting this and give it a try I will let you know what I find out - more to come. . .

Answer (score 1):

Also try looking at [Net::Nslookup](http://search.cpan.org/~darren/Net-Nslookup-2.01/lib/Net/Nslookup.pm) instead of using `nslookup ...`